# TokenRegex : create a new annotation key over List<String> annotation

Tags: java, stanford-nlp

I'm using stanford nlp tokenregex to configure rules. I created a new Annotation class of type List< String > and i would like to create a custom annotation key to use it in my rules :

```
mykey = { type: "ANNOKEY", value: "com.conjecto.semanlp.Annotations$CustomAnnotations" }

ENV.defaultStringPatternFlags = 2

{
   ruleType: "tokens",
   pattern: ( ( [ { mykey:"test" } ]) ),
   result: "TADAAM !"
}
```

It seems to be problematic to search over a List< String > annotation : i get an error in StringAnnotationPattern.match :

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.lang.String
```

But i see in the core the annotation key "gazetteer" which refer to the CoreAnnotations.GazetteerAnnotation.class :

```
public static class GazetteerAnnotation implements CoreAnnotation<List<String>> {
    public Class<List<String>> getType() {
      return ErasureUtils.uncheckedCast(List.class);
    }
  }
```

If i use this annotation key, same error. So how can i use the gazetteer/mykey annotation key to search a string over the list ?

Thank you,
Blaise

Comment: Can you please provide sample of code of when you try to set your custom annotation?

Comment: Are you trying to have an annotation per token that is a list of strings?  The pattern { key:"test" } is used to check for a match between a String annotation (like the word or part-of-speech) of a token and the word "test".  It is not used for annotations that are of the type List<String>.  TokensRegex currently don't support matching annotations of this type.  If you provide a concrete example of your use case and when you will have List<String> as an annotation, we can consider extending TokensRegex.